# How to convert nested JSON file into CSV using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

The code I'm using is following.
The screenshot is an output I am getting currently. I want expand `CVE_Items` column as well.

```
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_json('nvdcve-1.0-modified.json')
    df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Format of JSON. This is an NVD data from NVD website.

```
{
  "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "1000",
  "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2018-04-04T00:00Z",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
    "cve" : {
      "data_type" : "CVE",
      "data_format" : "MITRE",
      "data_version" : "4.0",
      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2001-1594",
        "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
      },
      "affects" : {
        "vendor" : {
          "vendor_data" : [ {
            "vendor_name" : "gehealthcare",
            "product" : {
              "product_data" : [ {
                "product_name" : "entegra_p&r",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "*"
                  } ]
                }
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      },
      "problemtype" : {
        "problemtype_data" : [ {
          "description" : [ {
            "lang" : "en",
            "value" : "CWE-255"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "references" : {
        "reference_data" : [ {
          "url" : "http://apps.gehealthcare.com/servlet/ClientServlet/2263784.pdf?DOCCLASS=A&REQ=RAC&DIRECTION=2263784-100&FILENAME=2263784.pdf&FILEREV=5&DOCREV_ORG=5&SUBMIT=+ACCEPT+"
        }, {
          "url" : "http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2015/07/10/vulnerable-breasts/"
        }, {
          "url" : "https://ics-cert.us-cert.gov/advisories/ICSMA-18-037-02"
        }, {
          "url" : "https://twitter.com/digitalbond/status/619250429751222277"
        } ]
      },
      "description" : {
        "description_data" : [ {
          "lang" : "en",
          "value" : "GE Healthcare eNTEGRA P&R has a password of (1) entegra for the entegra user, (2) passme for the super user of the Polestar/Polestar-i Starlink 4 upgrade, (3) 0 for the entegra user of the Codonics printer FTP service, (4) eNTEGRA for the eNTEGRA P&R user account, (5) insite for the WinVNC Login, and possibly other accounts, which has unspecified impact and attack vectors.  NOTE: it is not clear whether this password is default, hardcoded, or dependent on another system or product that requires a fixed value."
        } ]
      }
    },
    "configurations" : {
      "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
      "nodes" : [ {
        "operator" : "OR",
        "cpe" : [ {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpe22Uri" : "cpe:/a:gehealthcare:entegra_p%26r",
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:gehealthcare:entegra_p\\&r:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        } ]
      } ]
    },
    "impact" : {
      "baseMetricV2" : {
        "cvssV2" : {
          "version" : "2.0",
          "vectorString" : "(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C)",
          "accessVector" : "NETWORK",
          "accessComplexity" : "LOW",
          "authentication" : "NONE",
          "confidentialityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
          "integrityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
          "availabilityImpact" : "COMPLETE",
          "baseScore" : 10.0
        },
        "severity" : "HIGH",
        "exploitabilityScore" : 10.0,
        "impactScore" : 10.0,
        "obtainAllPrivilege" : false,
        "obtainUserPrivilege" : false,
        "obtainOtherPrivilege" : false,
        "userInteractionRequired" : false
      }
    },
    "publishedDate" : "2015-08-04T14:59Z",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2018-03-28T01:29Z"
  }, {
    "cve" : {
      "data_type" : "CVE",
      "data_format" : "MITRE",
      "data_version" : "4.0",
      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2002-2446",
        "ASSIGNER" : "cve@mitre.org"
      },
      "affects" : {
        "vendor" : {
          "vendor_data" : [ {
            "vendor_name" : "gehealthcare",
            "product" : {
              "product_data" : [ {
                "product_name" : "millennium_mg_firmware",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "-"
                  } ]
                }
              }
```

So I want to convert nested JSON into CSV where even nested columns will be part of CSV columns not as a JSON.

Output of script:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example output? How would you "flatten" CVE_Items which is an array?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_normalize`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('nvdcve-1.0-modified.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

df = json_normalize(data, 'CVE_Items', ['CVE_data_type', 'CVE_data_format', 'CVE_data_version', 'CVE_data_numberOfCVEs', 'CVE_data_timestamp'])
```

This will flatten the first level of nesting of `CVE_Items`. You will probably need to repeat this process to flatten some or all of the resulting columns as well, depending on how you want the final output to be.

For more details, refer to the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

This blog post can also be helpful:
[https://mindtrove.info/flatten-nested-json-with-pandas](http://Flatten%20nested%20json%20with%20pandas)

Comment: i did but gave me same output

Comment: can you show how to repeat for coming columns as well. I am new to python

Comment: For that you would need to provide a sample of how you want the final output to look like